# QubesOS: sys-usb and automatic connecting of keyboard and mouse to dom0?

Tags: linux, qubes-os

**I need to have USB mouse and keyboard attached to dom0, while sys-usb is handling the USB controller.**

I use sys-usb to have there bluetooth for headsets used in calls, also I want to have there all unknown devices, as this is my qube without network access and without root access.

There is only single USB controller available

I have modified policies in dom0

```
$ cat /etc/qubes-rpc/policy/qubes.InputKeyboard

sys-usb dom0 allow,user=root

$anyvm $anyvm deny

$ cat /etc/qubes-rpc/policy/qubes.InputMouse

sys-usb dom0 allow,user=root

$anyvm $anyvm deny
```

In /etc/default/grup I have:

```
usbcore.authorized_default=0
```

How this all is working? I don't understand it, so I'm not able to debug. Do you have any advice how I can configure it? Is this possible at all?

Best would be to whitelist the USB device by ID, I don't need any keyboard to be redirected to dom0, I need a specific one as I have a docking station, two external displays and there I need a keyboard, in other places I can use the keyboard built-in notebook.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1. Installed `qubes-input-proxy-sender`, `qubes-usb-proxy` (inside sys-usb VM).
2. Added user to groups audio, video (`usermod -a -G video user; usermod -a -G audio user`) (inside sys-usb VM)

The issue was probably caused by using Debian Minimal image instead of a regular image.